# How can I insert a file in SharePoint react SPFx web part using PnP library

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, react

How can I insert a file in SharePoint online using PnP library?

[image]

[image]

[image]

It is throwing error that `getFolderByServerRelativeUrl` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to `import { sp } from "@pnp/sp"`, in order to use `getFolderByServerRelativeUrl`.

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";

sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/documents/file.avi").getBlob().then((blob: Blob) => {});

sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/documents/file.avi").getBuffer().then((buffer: ArrayBuffer) => {});

sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/documents/file.json").getJSON().then((json: any) => {});

sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/documents/file.txt").getText().then((text: string) => {});

// all of these also work from a file object no matter how you access it
sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/documents").files.getByName("file.txt").getText().then((text: string) => {});
```

[@pnp/sp/files](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/v1/sp/docs/files/)